# ORA-01861 literal does not match format error when running within larger query

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm a newbie using Oracle SQL Developer, and running into some issues. When I run the following smaller sample query by itself, it runs fine:

```
 SELECT ((SYSDATE - TO_DATE(table1.a_certain_date_field, 'DD-MON-RR')) / 365.0)
 FROM &a_table
 WHERE rownum < 5 AND
 ((SYSDATE - TO_DATE(table1.a_certain_date_field, 'DD-MON-RR')) > 365.0);
```

But once I embed this into a larger query, I get an `ORA-01861 error: literal does not match format string`. For example, when I include it with other WHERE conditions, such as

```
    ...AND NOT (adr.state = 'WA')                                                                                                         
  AND
((SYSDATE - TO_DATE(table1.a_certain_date_field, 'DD-MON-RR')) > 365.0)...[more conditions]
```

What are some reasons why this would occur? My guess is that the table field changed the way that dates were inputted (ie. from DD-MM-YYYY to DD-MON-RR) at some point and caused this error to be thrown, but wouldn't take likewise throw a similar error in the smaller sample code?

Comment: Is the smaller sample code against the same table, database and schema?  If not you could have different results.

Comment: table1 in this case is being left joined to the main FROM statement, like this: LEFT JOIN &a_table table1 ON table1.acct_number = acct_number. But they are coming from the same database and schema.

Comment: one of the data format is not in the format that you are passing in to_date() function like you could be using SELECT TO_DATE('20171301','yyyy/mm/dd') FROM dual;

Comment: @Sandeep, that's what my initial suspicion was too. But why would the sample query run and execute correctly it there was an entry with an invalid data format? It's applying the same conditional logic on the same field range (table1.a_certain_date_field), and returns back valid results.

Comment: In the smaller query you are only looking at four rows (ROWNUM < 5). What happens when you remove that condition? You don't even need the rest of the query; just try `select to_date(<that date field>, 'dd-mon-rr') from <table>` (no `where` clause, nothing else). Do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always (in my experience) a data issue.  you can try to narrow it down by looking at various subsets of the data to find out which row/rows are causing it.

Comment: Thanks Roger. I'm going to try to write a function that to attempt parsing the string value in each date field row with TO_DATE([string value], 'DD-MON-RR'), return 0 if it passes, and 1 if it throws and exception. Then I should be able to see how many instances per field have non-valid date formats.

Comment: @YuChen, My pleasure.  Have a nice day.